# Identity comparison of properties in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to filter out instances of an object in an array (remove an observer from a list of observers to be specific):

```
private var observers = [ChooserObserver]()

...

func unregisterObserver(observer: ChooserObserver ) {
    observers = observers.filter { includeElement in includeElement === observer }
}

...

protocol ChooserObserver {
    var path: String { get set }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Type 'ChooserObserver' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

If I attempt to allow ChooserObserver to inherit AnyObject like so:

```
protocol ChooserObserver: AnyObject {
    var path: String { get set }
}
```

I am met with the following error:

> Cannot declare explicit conformance to the 'AnyObject' protocol

When I attempt to cast to AnyObject:

```
func unregisterObserver(observer: ChooserObserver ) {
    observers = observers.filter { includeElement in includeElement as AnyObject !== observer as AnyObject }
}
```

I get these errors:

> Partial application of struct method is not allowed
>
> Cannot downcast from 'ChooserObserver' to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'

I can only fix by appending @objc to my protocol in conjunction with the previous cast to AnyObject:

```
@objc protocol ChooserObserver {
    var path: String { get set }
}
```

Is this necessary, and if so why? I realize that an NSMutableSet would probably be appropriate here, but I am trying to understand Swift's type system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I attempt to allow ChooserObserver to inherit AnyObject like so:
>   I am met with the following error:

The correct syntax is

```
protocol ChooserObserver : class {
    //...
}
```

(Probably Apple should have just allowed you to do `: AnyObject` to avoid needing this new syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, maybe it works:

```
private var observerRefs = [AnyObject]()
private var observers = [ChooserObserver]()

...

func registerObserver<O where O: AnyObject, O: ChooserObserver>(observer: O) {
    observerRefs.append(observer)
    observers.append(observer)
}

func unregisterObserver<O where O: AnyObject, O: ChooserObserver>(observer: O) {
    for let index in (observerRefs.count - 1) .. 0 {
        if observerRefs[index] === observer {
            observerRefs.removeAtIndex(index)
            observers.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}

...

protocol ChooserObserver {
    var path: String { get set }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect my problems with inheriting AnyObject, which I neglected to demonstrate. I don't think Equatable would do any good, since the objects could not be distinguished based on property values.

Comment: Yeah I know that problem. I implemented an observer pattern in Swift and it was horrible to get it working... Didn't resolve your problem though.

Comment: I speculate this is related to a bug in the current version of Swift. The behavior is not ideal.

Comment: Replaced my answer with an alternative idea using generics. I'm on Windows right now so I cannot test it by myself.

Comment: So the real problem is that arrays cannot be defined to contain objects requiring multiple protocols. For instance, it would be necessary for a clean solution here to specify that the array would contain objects which conform to both AnyObject and ChooserObserver.

Comment: There it is, in the prerelease docs! [Class-Only Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_409)

Answer (score 1):

Protocols can be conformed by both class and value types. Identical operator only works for class instances. Identical to operator must be sure both operands are classes. I guess thats why there is such limitation. Objective-C value types cannot conform to protocols, thats why `@objc protocol ChooserObserver` works.

Comment: Yeah it would be really helpful if Apple would allow us to force a protocol to be only implementable by classes but not structs.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered what would happen with structs. I guess I'm too used to Java, where there are only classes and basic enums.

Comment: @fluidsonic: It does. `protocol ChooserObserver : class`